# How to assign two conditions to an input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML and JS code that will prompt user to input two values and then the system will show the byproduct of the two numbers. The Javascript code looks like this:

```
function multiplyBy()
{
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value; 
    num2 = document.getElementById("multiplier").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}
```

Now, for num1 input, the user can choose whether he wants to manually input the number or use a slider that will allow him to click on a specific value. The slider is built using html, and here I post the slider code in JS:

The Javascript code for num1 is:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;         
num1 = slider.value;
```

My question is, what code should I add to allow the user choose between manually input or use the slider? Right now I can only assign one input to num1.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is there a checkbox that says which to use?

Comment: How does the user indicate whether he wants to enter the number using the slider or manually?

Comment: What is `demo`? If it's an input, it doesn't make sense to assign to `output.innerHTML`. If it's a DIV, it doesn't make sense to use `output.value`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, so if the user inputs manually then the system will only account for that, and when the user use the slider the system will only use that input.

Comment: So it's whichever he interacts with last?

Comment: Yes, whichever one that he chooses. I will put something like "Please choose only one method to input the value..." above them.

Comment: Moving the slider updates the number displayed. Changing the number displayed moves the slider.

Comment: You're right, I edited to `num1 = slider.value`. So output.innerHTML is to show the value on screen if the user uses slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `change` event listeners to update `num1` whenever the user changes either the slider or the manual input.

```js
function save_num1() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.value;
}
document.getElementById("myRange").addEventListener("change", save_num1);
document.getElementById("firstNumber").addEventListener("change", save_num1);
```

```html
<input type="range" id="myRange" min="0" max="100">
<br>
<input type="number" id="firstNumber" min="0" max="100">
<br> Result: <span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks for the reply. But how do I incorporate your code to this: `function multiplyBy()
{
        num1 = document.getElementById("multiplier").value; 
        num2 = slider.value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}
` ?

Comment: `num1 = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;`